# How do I get the code to retrieve multiple search results (with a defined value I set) and populate multiple cells within google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Code:

```js
function getPerson(companyName, country, jobTitle) {

  var key = "AIzaSyAITL9pQFhBNT2NuL4xxurnuxusWfB3YB0"
  let searchEngineId = "82e8012da8c2c4d0b"
  let search = "site:linkedin.com/in intitle:" + jobTitle + " " + country + " " + companyName

  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
  };
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("``https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + key + "&q=" + search + "&cx=``" + searchEngineId, options);

  let url = JSON.parse(response).items[0].formattedUrl
  let title = JSON.parse(response).items[0].title.split("-")[0]

  var results = new Array(1);
  let info = new Array(2);
  info[0] = url
  info[1] = title
  results[0] = info

  return results
}
```

I'm still relatively new to code and haven't really tried much other than scouring the internet to try and find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to loop over the items. You now accesing only the first item with `items[0]` i used the `.forEach()` method on the array and store the results in a predetermined array:

```
function getPerson(companyName, country, jobTitle) {

  var key = "AIzaSyAITL9pQFhBNT2NuL4xxurnuxusWfB3YB0"
  let searchEngineId = "82e8012da8c2c4d0b"
  let search = "site:linkedin.com/in intitle:" + jobTitle + " " + country + " " + companyName

  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
  };
  
  const request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=${key}&q=${search}&cx=${searchEngineId}`, options);
  const data = JSON.parse(request.getContentText())
  const results = [];

  data.items.forEach(item => {
    const url = item.formattedUrl
    const title = item.title.split("-")[0]
    results.push([url, title])
  })
  
  return results
}
```